# Editor doesn't open in Xcode

Tags: xcode, editor

i have a weird problem with Xcode. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

When i usually clicked on the file in the left column it'd open in source code editor on the right. Now it doesn't happen. Does anyone know how to get it back the way it was before? it drives me crazy
greetings
peter

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you click on the Project, test, at the top, and then click in the columns on the right. Will it open the file in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode and relaunch it.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a little old now, but I had the same problem. The thing that I had to do was to open the "interface builder" program, wich is the editor for the file, then find and open the .xib file from that program. Next time I tried open it with Xcode it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Drag a source file from the Groups and Files pane (usually on the left) over into the pane that says "No Editor". No need to reset the defaults.